# Как вывести растровое изображение во весь экран?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Скиньте, пожалуйста ссылку или напишите здесь, исходный код программы выводящий во весь экран пиксели из массива значений каналов, на основе winApi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HDC hdc;
RECT rect;
hdc = GetDC(NULL);
GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rect);

int width = rect.right;
int height = rect.bottom;

COLORREF *arr = (COLORREF*)calloc(width * height, sizeof(COLORREF));

int counterItem = 0;
for (int i = 0;i <  height;i = i + 1)
{   
    for (int u = width;u >0 ;u = u - 1)
    {
        unsigned int chan[3] = { 0 };
        for (int q = 0;q < cChanel;q = q + 1)
        {
            chan[q] = pix[counterItem + q];
        }
        arr[(i*width)+ u] = RGB(chan[0], chan[1], chan[2]);
        counterItem = counterItem + cChanel;
    }
}

// Creating temp bitmap
HBITMAP map = CreateBitmap(width, height,1,8 * 4,(void*)arr);
// Temp HDC to copy picture
HDC src = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // hdc - Device context for window, I've got earlier with GetDC(hWnd) or GetDC(NULL);
SelectObject(src, map); // Inserting picture into our temp HDC
// Copy image from temp HDC to window
BitBlt(hdc,0,  0, width, height, src,0,  0,  SRCCOPY);
DeleteDC(src);
```